# scipy.optimize.minimize stop after n iterations without being better

Tags: python, scipy, minimization

I am looking to stop the [minimization of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) when there are **no improvment in score after n iterations**.

Like a **counter that reset** when the scipy minimization iteration find a best solution (minimum of score). When the counter go over a value, it stop searching and return the result.

There are the parameter `maxiter` in options but it take the total number of iterations insteed of number of iterations without progress.

Comment: Have you looked into the callback parameter for minimize

Comment: No, i will have a look at it, thx